# DB Connect task server not connection

Tags: splunk

I have installed DB connect app on my Splunk. Am facing Cannot communicate with the task server, please check your settings issue. I found below error in the logs.

> ERROR ExecProcessor - message from
>   "/home/iapsp02/etc/apps/splunk_app_db_connect/linux_x86_64/bin/server.sh"
>   com.splunk.modularinput.Event.writeTo(Event.java:65)\com.splunk.modularinput.EventWriter.writeEvent(EventWriter.java:134)\com.splunk.dbx.server.bootstrap.TaskServerStart.streamEvents(TaskServerStart.java:77)\com.splunk.modularinput.Script.run(Script.java:66)\com.splunk.modularinput.Script.run(Script.java:44)\com.splunk.dbx.server.bootstrap.TaskServerStart.main(TaskServerStart.java:150)\

and other error.

> ERROR ExecProcessor - message from
>   "/home/iapsp02/etc/apps/splunk_app_db_connect/linux_x86_64/bin/server.sh"
>   03:08:51.576 [main] INFO com.splunk.dbx.utils.TrustManagerUtil -
>   action=load_key_manager_succeed

Comment: Do you have the right driver installed for your DB?  See http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/DBX/3.1.3/DeployDBX/Installdatabasedrivers